# How can I get the number of real cores?

Tags: rust

The [num_cpus](https://crates.io/crates/num_cpus) crate gives me the number of cores, but this includes hyper threaded cores. In my case, this is significantly (almost 2x) slower than using a real core.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unfortunately questions about finding a library or a program are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev isn't this a sticky middle ground? OP isn't asking for a library, but just how to get the value. A library *may* be an answer, but the question doesn't require it.

Comment: This sounds like a feature request for num_cpus

Comment: http://libcpuid.sourceforge.net/index.html available from rust via, e.g., https://crates.io/crates/cpuid

Comment: And if you want a pure-Rust version that uses inline assembly (requiring nightly); there's [cupid](https://crates.io/crates/cupid).

Comment: libcpuid seems to have the information I'm requiring (while I couldn't find it in cupid) but now I need to decide of it's worth it to do that as it would complicate the build process quite a bit, I guess (having external dependencies).

Comment: Maybe doing it on the command line might be better. I only need to do this once during startup anyway.

Comment: Huh. Libcpuid simply [calls into the OS](https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid/blob/7c52fba50615659f8edeb9ec1564796117808ac6/libcpuid/cpuid_main.c#L85) to get the total number of CPUs. This seems to be the same thing as [num_cpus](https://github.com/seanmonstar/num_cpus/blob/ac827925a1f3125a7441042ba661ed311c1abe68/src/lib.rs). Which data from libcpuid are you using?

Comment: I actually didn't try myself. Well, I realized that the performance difference isn't that big anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using rust [binding](https://github.com/daschl/hwloc-rs) for [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) library as described in this blog [post](http://nitschinger.at/Discovering-Hardware-Topology-in-Rust/).

It can be used under various platforms and allows you to get count of physical cores and logical processing units (in case of hyperthreading) like this (code from blog post):

```
extern crate hwloc;

use hwloc::{Topology, ObjectType};

fn main() {
    // Create a new Topology
    let topology = Topology::new();

    // Get all objects with type "Core"
    let cores = topology.objects_with_type(&ObjectType::Core);

    // Match on the returned Result and print the length if successful.
    match cores {
       Ok(c) => println!("There are {} cores on this machine.", c.len()),
       Err(e) => panic!(format!("Could not load cores because of: {:?}", e))
    }
}
```